# Elegantly using JavaScript on widget admin forms

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, ajax, javascript, backbone

I'm working on a project involving a lot of widgets, and I'm thinking it'd be really great to have a "More options" section built using jQuery UI Accordion that expands when clicked.

So, I've enqueued 'jquery-ui-accordion' using the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' action:

```
function add_my_deps() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
}    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_deps' );
```

...And my JavaScript looks something like this:

```
(function($){
    $('.more-options-expansible').accordion();
})(jQuery)
```

**Now what?**

If I enqueue that via the "add_my_deps" action above, it only works if I reload the page (I.e., when placing the widget, the JavaScript is instantiated before the element is created; if the widget is saved, its JavaScript is enqueued as normal and it instantiates as normal.).

If I place that in a `<script>` tag at the end of my HTML output in my widget's `form()` method, I get the following exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'`. This is because it seems to be instantiating the accordion via the inline `<script>` before the jQuery UI Accordion library is loaded.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I'm using a simple jQuery instantiation for this example, but it seems like I'd have even worse issues if I tried to do anything using AJAX (Namely, how would I select the appropriate element to place the response in? Is this something I need to start using Backbone.js to accomplish?).

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing Javascript When a Widget is Added in the Backend](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/executing-javascript-when-a-widget-is-added-in-the-backend)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the my answer with my findings from a previous question, this should now set you straight.

It's going to fail because when the JS runs it's being instantiated against the hidden widget form in the left hand side. It turns out when you drag the widget to an active sidebar it actually clones the hidden form into the right hand side, as opposed to ajaxing in it's contents. This means, the new widget you've added already has `accordion` instantiated against it, but due to the cloning things do not work so well initially. Though obviously after a page refresh it will work perfectly.

To make it work as intended when we add a new widget, we need to target our form content that is in the right hand side of the page, we can also hook onto the `ajaxstop` event, instead of load. This is because after the cloned widget is dropped into the right hand side, WordPress sends an ajax request to save the widgets position.

```
$(document).on('ajaxstop', '#widget-right .more-options-expansible', function(e){
    $(this).accordion();
});
```

This leads to a nicer solution than adding the JS inline and allows you to keep the scripts in the footer.

Comment: I'm assuming you want me to instantiate that via `wp_enqueue_script()`? If so, it does not seem to work -- the anonymous function never fires.

Comment: If you're on the admin side, you want to conditionally enqueue based on the admin page. For widgets it might look like this:  
  
`// Only enqueue scripts & style on necessary pages
function my_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    if( 'widgets.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script('widget-js');
    wp_enqueue_style('iwdget-css');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');`

Comment: Sorry about the run-on block there. I never have figured out the right way to add code & line breaks in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this I've discovered since posting the above question is to instantiate inline via `WP_Widget::form()`, with `wp_enqueue_script()` loading the necessary JavaScript (exactly as mentioned above) -- except, and here's the key part, load the JavaScript **in the header** instead of the footer (fifth argument of `wp_enqueue_script()`).

Which makes a lot of sense now that I think about it.

Even still, I hate using inline JavaScript -- ever -- and loading everything in the header is less than ideal.

As such, am leaving this question open in case anyone has a better idea.

Comment: I now know what the actual issue is, you can see my answer for another question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/executing-javascript-when-a-widget-is-added-in-the-backend

Answer (score 1):

WordPress added a few JavaScript events, 'widget-added', 'widget-updated', 'widget-synced' so you no longer need to hack the ajax event.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19675

So, I think you should update the code to something like this in your external js file:

```
$(document).on('widget-added', function(event, widget) {
   $(widget).find('.more-options-expansible').accordion();
}
```

You probably need to add similar for 'widget-updated' and 'widget-synced' as they all affect your dom.